# Can I tell from the group how the endomorphism rings of its representations will look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, representation-theory, division-algebras

Let $G$ be a *finite* group. It is known that the endomorphism ring of an irreducible real representation $\rho: G\to\mathrm{GL}(\Bbb R^d)$ is (isomorphic to) either $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb H$ (the quaternions). I realize more and more that there are big gaps in my knowledge with regards to this result.

For example, I do know very little about which groups and which representations will produce what type of endomorphism ring. My ignorance goes so far that I do not even know whether the type of endomorphism ring is essentially a property of the group (independent of the [faithful] representation), or whether it can vary from representation to representation.

> **Question.** Are there group theoretic properties of $G$ by which I can tell whether all (or at least some) irreducible (faithful) representations of $G$ will have endomorphism ring $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb H$? Can a group have (faithful) irreducible representations with different endomorphism rings?

I could sleep even better if I knew that there exists a complete classification or characterization of the groups with a particular type of endomorphism ring. Of course, classifying finite groups is probably too much to ask for, but I always had the (potentially naive) hope that most representations of most groups have endomorphism ring $\Bbb R$. Can this be made precise?

> **Question.** Do most irreducible representations of most groups  have endomorphism ring $\Bbb R$? That is, is it tractable to classify the remaining groups/representations with ring $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb H$?

Comment: Can clear this up right away: the division algebra depends on which rep you're talking about.

Comment: @runway44 Great, thank you! I assume this holds true if we restrict to faithful reps. Of course, there are many follow ups: can I see on the group if *any* rep has a "special" endomorphism ring? Or for what groups do *all* reps have the same ring? I believe that the finite subgroups of $\mathrm U(n)$ are such groups. Or is it in general a very wild business, there are no early warnings and the rings have to be checked on a case by case basis for every group and every rep?

Comment: @M.Winter: Since the trivial representation has real type, if all representations of $G$ have the same type then they are all real type. Also, all finite groups are finite subgroups of $U(n)$ (take a faithful representation of the group, and use the averaging argument to produce an invariant Hermitian form). By the way, do you know about the Frobenius-Schur indicator? It allows you to check the type of a representation given its character table, and knowing how to "square" conjugacy classes.

Comment: @Joppy Thank you. I think the fact that every group is a subgroup of $\mathrm U(n)$ (which has no absolutely irreducible real representations) convincingly shows that not too much can be read from the abstract finite group itself. Yes, I am aware of the Frobenius-Schur indicator. But it is not exactly what I am looking for. I had hoped for easy purely group-theoretic criteria, but this hope seems shattered.